# Function works in VBA but returns #value in the worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

With the code below, I am looking to use a referenced cell's value to xlookup another value from another workbook. The code works perfectly when I Debug.Print in a sub and step through it. However, when I try to call the function directly from a worksheet, it returns #value.

```
Option Explicit
Function FirstDC(SC As Variant) As Variant

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim win As Window
Dim rngSC As Range
Dim rngDC As Range
Dim Result As String
Dim Temp As String

Set wb = Workbooks.Open("\\dtc\files\ECS-Customer\Enterprise Solution Design and Implementation\Macro Files\Serving DC Lookup.xlsx")
Set ws = wb.Sheets("Terms Load Points")
Set rngSC = ws.Range("A2:A250")
Set rngDC = ws.Range("F2:F250")
Set win = ActiveWorkbook.Windows(1)

win.Visible = False

On Error GoTo ErrHandler

Result = Application.WorksheetFunction.XLookup(SC, rngSC, rngDC)

Temp = Result
wb.Close SaveChanges:=False

Result = Temp
FirstDC = "'" & Right("000" & Result, 3)

ErrHandler:
  If Err.Number <> 0 Or FirstDC = "'000" Then
    FirstDC = "N/A"
  End If
    
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Function
```

The code should return a value such as " '001 " or " N/A ".

Comment: `Workbooks.Open` is going to fail in a UDF. There are some tricks, as outlined in the linked thread.

Comment: @BigBen Thank you! I'll look into the work arounds.